# Phonegap iOS merges appears with red color

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have created a simple PhoneGap application for iOS using **CLI (Command Line Interface)**. [Reference Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) After opening sample project I found file named **merges red coloured**.

What is this all about and why does it shows in red color?

[image: Error screenshot]